# Regex pattern fetching no matches

Tags: java, regex, parsing, ping

Some string patterns that I'm using are not fetching me a match at runtime, while when I use a regex checker online such as [Regular Expression Tester](http://myregexp.com/), I am shown that my pattern fetches me the desired output.

```
public class RegexMatches
{
    public static void main( String args[] ){
        String input = "[1463895254]PING www.andi.dz (213.179.181.44) 100(128) bytes of data.[1463895254]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=195 ms[1463895255]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=202 ms[1463895256]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=180 ms[1463895257]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=200 ms[1463895258]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=5 ttl=54 time=206 ms[1463895259]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=6 ttl=54 time=188 ms[1463895260]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=7 ttl=54 time=182 ms[1463895261]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=8 ttl=54 time=223 ms[1463895263]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=9 ttl=54 time=187 ms[1463895263]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=10 ttl=54 time=199 ms";

        try{
            String op[] = parseIndividualIP(input);
            System.out.println(op[1]);             
            System.out.println(op[8]);                 
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

// Doesn't Work...
    public static String[] parseIndividualIP(String input) throws IPAddressNotFoundException {
        // Capture the ip-address after 'x byes from'
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("bytes\\s+from\\s+([\\d,\\.]+):");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        if (m.find()){
            int i = 0;
            String[] s = new  String[10];
            while(m.find()){
                s[i] = m.group(++i);
            }
            return s;
        }
        else
            throw new IPAddressNotFoundException();
    }

}
```

I don't know why at runtime I have no matches and how I should be debugging this problem. As the pattern was cross-checked before and after running.

Input String -

```
[1463895254]PING www.andi.dz (213.179.181.44) 100(128) bytes of data.[1463895254]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=195 ms[1463895255]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=202 ms[1463895256]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=180 ms[1463895257]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=200 ms[1463895258]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=5 ttl=54 time=206 ms[1463895259]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=6 ttl=54 time=188 ms[1463895260]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=7 ttl=54 time=182 ms[1463895261]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=8 ttl=54 time=223 ms[1463895263]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=9 ttl=54 time=187 ms[1463895263]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=10 ttl=54 time=199 ms
```

Regex Pattern Used -

```
bytes\\s+from\\s+([\\d,\\.]+):
```

Comment: `if (m.find()){` - > `while (m.find()){`, and no need using a nested `m.find`

Comment: See http://ideone.com/PVauJK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is using `m.group(++i)`. In you regular expression you have one capturing group that captures the IP Address (`([\\d,\\.]+)`), which means you should be invoking `m.group(1)` as that returns the string captured by the first group.

The Pattern object is thread safe, so it can be compiled once and the same instance reused.

The following code contains the group fix and also some modifications for readability. Changed the usage of arrays to linked list and instead of throwing exception the method returns and empty list if no matches found.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches {
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("bytes\\s+from\\s+([\\d,\\.]+):");

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = "[1463895254]PING www.andi.dz (213.179.181.44) 100(128) bytes of data.[1463895254]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=195 ms[1463895255]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=202 ms[1463895256]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=180 ms[1463895257]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=200 ms[1463895258]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=5 ttl=54 time=206 ms[1463895259]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=6 ttl=54 time=188 ms[1463895260]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=7 ttl=54 time=182 ms[1463895261]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=8 ttl=54 time=223 ms[1463895263]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=9 ttl=54 time=187 ms[1463895263]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=10 ttl=54 time=199 ms";

        List<String> op = parseIndividualIP(input);
        op.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static List<String> parseIndividualIP(String input) {
        Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(input);
        List<String> ips = new LinkedList<>();
        while (m.find()) {
            ips.add(m.group(1));
        }
        return ips;
    }
}
```